# The whole vs all

Tags: determiners

Does **the whole summer** and **all summer** have the same meanings?

> I spent ***the whole/all*** summer in the village.

Comment: In this context, yes, they mean the same thing.  Could you please add more detail to explain why you find this confusing?

Comment: Yes: when used with singular heads, the determinative "all" is in competition with the adjective "whole". They both function as determiners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applied to a singular noun, *all* means the same as *whole* (or *the whole*, *the whole of*, etc). If it were applied to a plural or mass noun, it would means the same as *every* used with a singular (In the case of the plural) or the semantically similar idea applied to a mass noun.